# JMeter: How to switch between tabs in Java using WebDriver Sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (WDS.browser.getWindowHandles());
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

It works in WebDriver with the driver variable, but produces the error in the WebDriver Sampler:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import ja . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 24, column 25.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import ja . . . '' at line number 24
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:81)
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:76)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very outdated scripting engine which does not support [diamond operators](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) which where introduced in Java 7 while `beanshell` and `bsh` are stuck at Java 5 language level therefore you won't be able to use modern language features.

You have the following options:

1. Remove diamond operators like:

   ```
   ArrayList tabs2 = new ArrayList (WDS.browser.getWindowHandles());
   ```
2. Switch to [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting engine. Groovy is more Java-compliant, valid Java code in 99% of cases will be valid groovy code so problems like this will go away. Moreover, Groovy performs much better, for WebDriver Sampler it is not that important, but it is vital for other scripting tasks. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri for suggestions. I'll try the option 1 tomorrow. I do not want to switch to Groovy. The whole point is to reuse our Java WebDriver scripts in JMeter.  By switching to another language, we need to re-write everything from scratch.

Comment: As it evidenced by the error you are getting, choosing `java` in the "Script Language" dropdown doesn't really mean "java", it is being interpreted by BSH scripting engine so I would recommend trying out Groovy, most likely you won't have to change a single line of code, it will just start working. Also be aware that you could use [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler if your Selenium tests are developed using [JUnit framework](http://junit.org/)

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri once again. I know about JUnit Request Sampler, but I thought that the specialized WebDriver Sampler could be better. Which one do you recommend? Also when I replaced ChromeDriver to HtmlUnitDriver in the JUnit Request Sampler, some elements stopped being recognizable anymore.